# WebDrive problems on mac

Tags: macos, mac, ftp

Has anyone had this problem before?

[image]

I get this when I try to mount a FTP drive.

Comment: Can you please post "the Console logfile"... I think this will give us "more information"

Answer (score 0):

Like the message says look in the console - top right search box type in console.
Look for anything with ftp in the line (you can search on this), then post the errors back here.

Another possibility is to try [cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) which is a free ftp client, to see if it's a general problem.  Also check with the supplier of the webspace you're using to see if there are problems on their end.